# Write output to log file in released Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to write printf() type outputs to a log file in Android app.
This should happen for the released apk file running on my end users phones.
The vast examples from Google are for debug apk file which the developer is testing and this is not what I am asking for.
Some examples also suggest writing to SD card, but these days Pixel devices do not have external storage, only insternal storage.
So I am asking this because answers from 10 years ago are no longer valid.
How to write to a logfile.txt in Android phones programatically using Kotlin?
Where should the location of this file beso that Android does not automatically delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to write printf() type outputs to a log file in Android app. This should happen for the released apk file running on my end users phones.

You might prefer a hosted logging solution.

> Some examples also suggest writing to SD card, but these days Pixel devices do not have external storage, only insternal storage

All Android devices have external storage, [at least as the Android SDK uses the term](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> How to write to a logfile.txt in Android phones programatically using Kotlin? Where should the location of this file beso that Android does not automatically delete it?

Use standard Java file I/O. If you only need your app to have access to the logs, use `getFilesDir()` on `Context` to get a good directory to use. If you want your user to have an option of accessing the logs, use `getExternalFilesDir()` on`Context` to get a good directory to use.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Can you please tell me whether Log.d() or println() will work for the released version of apk? I am confused because I read it only works for the debug version of the apk. I already am using VPS where my server is running from. Do you recommend printing to file with getFilesDir() and then uploading that file to the server at a certain frequency like daily or weekly?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: "Can you please tell me whether Log.d() or println() will work for the released version of apk?" -- neither, if your objective is to log to a file. "I am confused because I read it only works for the debug version of the apk" -- neither logs to a file, on `debug` or `release` builds, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: "Do you recommend printing to file with getFilesDir() and then uploading that file to the server at a certain frequency like daily or weekly?" -- personally I would use an existing remote logging solution, after having worked out a suitable redaction system to ensure I am not logging anything that might get me sued. I would also use Timber or a similar logging framework, so I can replace where logging goes without having to change each of the places where I do that logging.

Comment: "neither logs to a file, on debug or release builds" -> Ohh ok now I get it why its not working. My server code is also in Kotlin and I am using println() to be directed to a log file using shell script. Now I get it that you cannot do similar logging in Android client.

Comment: " to ensure I am not logging anything that might get me sued" -> I am adding a button in the app which the user explicitly presses to upload the log file to my server, so that is with user consent. I am tight on budget to pay for remote logging. I guess I will use getFilesDir() and using FileStream to write to log file. I can then http the contents to my server when the user presses the upload button.

Comment: The logcat in Android Studio seems to be printing so much more information than what I am printing in my code. Is there a way to get that into the file created with getFilesDir()?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: "Is there a way to get that into the file created with getFilesDir()?" -- no, sorry.